# JQuery UI tabs - reload after clicking button

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-ui-tabs

I know there are people who posted a similar problem on this page already, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have two tables, you can switch between them by clicking on a tab (JQuery TABS).
JQuery Tablesorter is also applied to sort the tables.

Next to each entry of the table is a button, by clicking on that button, the entry is then moved to the other table and vanishes from the current one. That works, but I have to **refresh the page or switch to the other tab everytime I hit the button to see the changes.** 
Is there a way to do that automatically?

Here is part of my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.newPanel.find("#domainsTable").trigger('applyWidgets');
}
});
    });
 function reserve(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "reserve.php?geraeteID=" + id,
                cache: false,
                complete: function (data) {
                    $("#tabs").tabs('load', 0);

                }
            });
        }

        function dereserve(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "userdereserve.php?geraeteID=" + id,
                cache: false,
                complete: function (data) {
                    $("#tabs").tabs('load', 1);


                }
            });
        }   
</script>
<body>
    <img src="bvu.png" width="1660" height="375" alt="grafik">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="geraete.php">Geräte</a></li>
            <li><a href="myreservations2.php">Reservierungen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The functions "reserve" and "dereserve" is called when you hit the button.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: clone the content to the new tab, remove content from the old

Comment: Sorry that does not help me here :(